# Forbidden 403 when accessing Microsoft Graph from a dotnet core application

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to pull the office location for an authenticated azure active directory user through microsoft graph but keep receiving a 403 Forbidden response.

I am able to authenticate and I can generate an access token but the http response status code is always 403.

Here is some code I have been working with but I have a feeling it may be due to configuration or permissions so please let me know what additional information you would need.

```
public class AccountService : IAccountService
{
    private readonly AzureAd _adSettings;

    public AccountService(IOptions<AzureAd> adSettings)
    {
        _adSettings = adSettings.Value;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetStoreIdFromUser(string userId)
    {
        var storeId = string.Empty;

        string accessToken = await GetBearerAccesToken();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, GetUserUrl(userId)))
            {
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        var json = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                        storeId = json?["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"]?.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return storeId;
    }

    #region private methods

    private string GetUserUrl(string userPrincipalName)
    {
        return string.Format("https://graph.windows.net/{0}/users/{1}?{2}", _adSettings.TenantId, userPrincipalName, "api-version=1.6");
    }

    private async Task<string> GetBearerAccesToken()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        // Get OAuth token using client credentials 
        string authString = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + _adSettings.TenantId;

        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString, false);

        // Config for OAuth client credentials  
        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(_adSettings.ClientId, _adSettings.AppKey);
        string resource = "https://graph.windows.net";

        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);
        result = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

        return result;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to access Microsoft Graph or Azure AD Graph?

Comment: Should be Microsoft Graph.  I added permissions for that in my AD app registration.

Comment: 403 means "I know who you are, but you can't access this thing." Check the token at https://jwt.io, and see that the audience claim (aud) is the Microsoft Graph resource URI (`https://graph.microsoft.com`), and that the necessary roles are in the token.

Comment: showing Aud of https://graph.windows.net.  Can I just updated that to the new endpoint or will I need to rewrite the code?

Comment: the roles in the token are "Directory.Read.All"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the original code on github after watching an awesome Pluralsight course Building a Global App with Azure PaaS by Barry Luijbregts.

@juunas pointed me in the right direction in the comments.  I was using the wrong API.

this is the working code:

```
public interface IAccountService
{
    Task<string> GetStoreIdFromUser(string userId);
}

public class AccountService : IAccountService
{
    private readonly AzureAd _adSettings;

    public AccountService(IOptions<AzureAd> adSettings)
    {
        _adSettings = adSettings.Value;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetStoreIdFromUser(string userId)
    {
        var storeId = string.Empty;

        string accessToken = await GetBearerAccesToken();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, GetUserUrl(userId)))
            {
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        var json = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                        storeId = json?["officeLocation"]?.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return storeId;
    }

    #region private methods

    private string GetUserUrl(string userPrincipalName)
    {
        return string.Format("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{0}", userPrincipalName);
    }

    private async Task<string> GetBearerAccesToken()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        // Get OAuth token using client credentials 
        string authString = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + _adSettings.TenantId;

        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString, false);

        // Config for OAuth client credentials  
        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(_adSettings.ClientId, _adSettings.AppKey);
        string resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";

        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);
        result = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

        return result;
    }

    #endregion
}
```